# Perl Count elements in array of hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am calling a webservice that returns an array of hash records as response.

my $triggers = $zabbix->raw('trigger','get', $options);
print Dumper($triggers);

Dumper output is as follows

```
      $VAR1 = [
      {
        'lastchange' => '1422765352',
        'triggerid' => '10430011'
      },
      {
        'lastchange' => '1422617151',
        'triggerid' => '604979'
      },
     ]
```

Sometimes i get only 1 record as response. How do i count the no of records returned?

I tried using my $trig_count = @{$triggers}; but this fails when there is only 1 record set returned.

Suggestions that will work for both the cases

Comment: What do you mean by `this fails when there is only 1 record set returned.` It works pretty fine and gives `1` in `$trig_count`. What do you expect?

Comment: what is the dumper output where there is only one record?  I'm guessing there is no array then...

Answer (score 0):

If your data is either a single hash ref or an array reference:

```
my $trig_count = ref $trigger eq 'HASH' || scalar @$triggers;
```